# probability question - virus damage computer

Tags: probability

A certain computer virus can damage any file with probability $35$%, independently of other files. Suppose this virus enters a folder containing $2400$ files. Compute the probability that between $800$ and $850$ files get damaged.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CDF of a binomial distribution with $p=0.35$ and $n=2400$ evaluated at $x_1 = 799$ and $x_2 = 850$.

Comment: can be more explicity, please ?

Comment: Sure. You want the probability that a random variables takes values beteen 800 and 850, i.e., $P(800 \leq X \leq 850)$. Since the cumulative distribution captures everything to the left of your cutoff point, it follows that $P(800 \leq X \leq 850) = P(X \leq 850) - P(X \leq 799)$. The only thing left is to model $X$. Since the events are independent, you are looking at basically flippint 2400 biased coins, where each coin has a $0.35$ probability of showing "heads" (infecting a file). Counting all heads across all flips is your binomial distribution.

Comment: is not $P(X \geq 799)$?

Comment: No, because you said between 800 and 850. If you say $ \geq 799$, that includes 851, 852, etc.